# Navigation item change doesn't update recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a DrawerLayout Activity with a Navigation View. The items are "Home", "About Us" "Events Schedule", etc. The Events Schedule has a fragment which contains a bottom navigation drawer and a view pager. There are only 2 fragments attached to the viewpager - Day 1 schedule and Day 2 schedule. Likewise, there is only 2 items in the bottom navigation. Each of these fragments has a recycler view where I display the list of events and their date & time.

When I launch the app, the home page fragment pops up as expected. I go to the navigation drawer and click on "Events Schedule". The recycler view loads the data. I can swipe on the view pager. Everything works fine.

But now when I click on "About us", that fragment opens up as usual. And when I reopen "Events and Schedule", the recycler view doesn't display any list items. It works for the first time I click it, but not the second, third and so on.

EventsFragment.kt (the main fragment with viewpager and bottom navigation):

```
class EventsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_events) {

    ...

    private fun setupViewPager() {
        binding.viewPagerScheduleDay.adapter = EventDayPagerAdapter(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager)
        binding.bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.mDay1 -> binding.viewPagerScheduleDay.currentItem = 0
                R.id.mDay2 -> binding.viewPagerScheduleDay.currentItem = 1
            }
            true
        }
    }
}
```

EventDayFragment.kt (Fragment inside the viewpager):

```
class EventDayFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_event_day) {
    
    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding = FragmentEventDayBinding.bind(view)

        val day = arguments?.getInt(PARAM_1)!!
        loadDataToRecyclerView(day)
    }

    private fun loadDataToRecyclerView(day: Int) {
        Database.getEventsFromDay(day) { events ->
            events?.let {
                val eventAdapter = EventScheduleRecyclerAdapter(requireContext(), it)
                binding.recyclerViewEventsSchedule.apply {
                    layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, VERTICAL)
                    adapter = eventAdapter
                    setHasFixedSize(true)
                }
            } ?: requireContext().toast("Error Encountered in collecting data.")
        }
    }
}
```

In my code, I noticed that in EventDayFragment.kt, The onViewCreated function is called only once. That's why the recyclerview works only once. How do I fix this?

**Edit**

```
class EventDayFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_event_day) {
    
    companion object {
        ...
        var isAlive = false
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        isAlive = true
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding = FragmentEventDayBinding.bind(view)

        val day = arguments?.getInt(PARAM_1)!!
        loadDataToRecyclerView(day)
    }

    private fun loadDataToRecyclerView(day: Int) {
        ... // Same as before
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        isAlive = false
    }
}
```

I have added a static boolean variable to know if the the fragment is running or not. From the EventsFragment, I added this code to `setupViewPager()`:

```
    private fun setupViewPager() {
        val eventDayFragmentAdapter = EventDayFragmentAdapter(
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
        )
        binding.viewPagerScheduleDay.adapter = eventDayFragmentAdapter

        val fragment = eventDayFragmentAdapter.getItem(binding.viewPagerScheduleDay.currentItem)
        if (EventDayFragment.isAlive)
            fragment.loadDataToRecyclerView(binding.viewPagerScheduleDay.currentItem + 1)
        binding.bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.mDay1 -> binding.viewPagerScheduleDay.currentItem = 0
                R.id.mDay2 -> binding.viewPagerScheduleDay.currentItem = 1
            }
            true
        }
    }
```

After doing this Edit, I am getting this error: EventDayFragment is not attached to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that child fragment's `onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` was not called everytime I create the view of the parent fragment. This was because of this one line of code:

```kotlin
binding.viewPagerScheduleDay.adapter = EventDayPagerAdapter(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager)
```

Passing the activity's FragmentManager didn't tell the application to create child fragments' views everytime.

Instead, we have to add this code:

```kotlin
binding.viewPagerScheduleDay.adapter = EventDayPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
```

This works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Why:
That's correct the EventDayFragment view is not destroyed, so onViewCreated gets called only once in the first time the data will work and the children fragments of the EventsSchedule are created(as I understand EventSchedule contains viewPager and two children fragments Day 1 schedule and Day 2 schedule), but when you click on About us, the EventsSchedule fragment itself won't be destroyed but this does not necessarily apply for it's children(Day 1 schedule and Day 2 schedule) and the children might be destroyed, when they get created again in the second time, they won't find the data(because the parent was not destroyed like them)

How to solve it:
There are many solutions in my opinion:

1. Inside the onViewCreated() of the children fragments ask the parent fragment for the data and make the loadDataToRecyclerView(day) inside the children fragments themselves.
2. (Quick but not recommended)try to move the loadDataToRecyclerView(day) into the
   onResume() instead of the onViewCreated()

Comment: Thank you. I understood about the parent fragment destroying but not necessarily the children. I know that putting `loadDataToRecyclerView(day)` in onResume() would be correct. However, I didn't understand what you meant in the 1st solution.

Comment: welcome, happy to help. First sol: you have two fragments right? both have onViewCreated, the first solution says that find a way to load the data to recyclerview inside the onViewCreated of the child fragment may be by asking the parent to do that via a callback interface between them(because as u said, onViewCreated of the Parent won't be called, but onViewCreated of the child will be recalled) and I recommend this solution more than the second because this way you are sure that the data won't be loaded into the recyclerview unless the child view is created.

Comment: If I use the callback interface, I am gonna need to get the instance of the Fragment. Since the fragment is shown via the viewpager, how will I get the fragment? R.id class doesn't have the id of the child fragment and I don't know how to register any tag with it.

Comment: I also moved ```loadDataToRecyclerView(day)``` to ```onResume()``` method but still the I only see the bottom navigation, not the recyclerview

Comment: to get the parent fragment use getParentFragment() (But make sure not to call it before the onViewCreated because it will give you null)

Comment: regarding calling loadDataToRecyclerView(day) inside the onResume(), I don't recommend this solution becuase it hides an issue so don't use it, stick to using interface callback methods, it's much cleaner solution.

Comment: I would use the getChildFragmentManager(), right? Because onViewCreated() is called everytime on the parent fragment; that's why I can see the bottom nav.

Comment: If you want to get childFragments yes you should the childFragmentManager (sorry using kotlin, there is no need to use getChildFragmentManager())

Comment: I am still facing an error and it's not working. Can you please check the edit I have made?

Comment: I have solved my problem without using any callback methods. Look at the accepted answer.